# ERROR 1524 (HY000): Plugin 'unix_socket' is not loaded mysql

Tags: debian, mysql

[image: Ps: i'm using my root account]

mysql is giving me this error when I try to access it for the first time.

It's not working for me; I have Parrot OS, which is based on Debian Jessie. The problem started with adding the mysql repository, then the package installation (of mysqlserver etc); after all of that, I'm facing this error. I tried the procedure that you sent but at the last command it's giving me error 2002 which is probably caused by the stop command at the beginning.

Comment: This may possibly help: https://askubuntu.com/questions/705458/ubuntu-15-10-mysql-error-1524-unix-socket

Comment: it's not working with me, i have Parrot OS which is based on debian jessie, the problem started with adding mysql repository then the package installation (of mysqlserver ecc....), after all of that i'm facing this error, i tried the procedure that you sent but at the last command it's giving me error 2002 which is probably caused by the stop command at the beginning

Answer (score 7):

I've ran into a similar problem and got it working using this solution.

**STEP 1: ADD UNIX AUTHENTICATION PLUGIN TO MARIADB CONFIG**

Change the file `/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf`

Add the line below `[mysqld]` section.

```
plugin-load-add = auth_socket.so
```

Restart the server and you should log using

```
sudo mysql -u root
```

That's it!
It seems that Mariadb developpers have found a new approach for identifying based on the actual user, so they made an extension that allow you: if you're `user1` on Linux and there happen to be a MySQL user named `user1` then he will be logged in without a password based on the socket file (the last sentence is just my understanding 
I could be wrong or imprecise).

The bottom line you're good with the first step unless want the old identification behavior then move to step2 :

**STEP 2: CHANGE TO STANDARD AUTHENTICATION**
Run the following commands

```
use mysql;
update user set plugin='' where User='root';
flush privileges;
exit
```

[Source and more info](https://websiteforstudents.com/fix-mariadb-plugin-unix_socket-is-not-loaded-error-on-ubuntu-17-04-17-10/)

Comment: In some cases which etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf does not exist edit /etc/mysql/my.cnf and it will work.